# how could i get the tooltip alignment fixed

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

how could i get the tooltip alignment fixed, so that the tooltip shows above the bar

http://jsbin.com/mutirodawa/edit?html,output

```js
 bar
   .on("mousemove", function(d) {
     divTooltip.style("right", d3.event.pageX + 30 + "px");
     divTooltip.style("top", d3.event.pageY + 45 + "px");
     divTooltip.style("display", "inline-block");
     var x = d3.event.pageX,
       y = d3.event.pageY
     var elements = document.querySelectorAll(':hover');
     l = elements.length
     l = l - 1
     elementData = elements[l].__data__
     divTooltip.html(elementData.name + "<br>" + elementData.value);
   });
 bar
   .on("mouseout", function(d) {
     divTooltip.style("display", "none");
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the tooltip showing above each bar, I attached the handler to each bar individually:

http://jsbin.com/pixicunasi/1/edit?html,js,output